# How can I display this large number of categories and subcategories responsively?

Tags: usability, website-design, gui-design, mobile, design-patterns

Working on a website which will have blog posts and those posts will have categories. Those categories will have subcategories. So 2 level of categories which potentially adds up to well over hundreds.

See screenshot from my header, displaying so far only the top level categories:
[image: My header and a subheader bar displaying top level categories]

I realise this subheader idea won't work because of responsivity problems. What is the ideal way of showing a bunch of different categories, which would work both for desktop and mobile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When looking at your navbar I'm reminded of a horizontal scrolling navbar.

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_menu_horizontal_scroll.asp

I can't really find the article it is referenced in, but it was an article about alternatives to an off-canvas/drawer/hamburger menu.

The article mentioned a big American news outlet using the navigation on their site, but I don't remember which site is was.
They put the most important links at the front and the least important at the back.

It might result in a very long, scrollable bar.

Personally, I think a better solution might be a mega dropdown.

https://codyhouse.co/demo/mega-dropdown/index.html#0

This example is responsive and can hold a lot of links over multiple levels.

I also would like to comment on the sheer number of links on the same level. I recommend reducing the number of categories per level. You might have to create more levels, but it will help with discoverability. I base this on [Hick's law](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hick's_law), [Miller's law](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Magical_Number_Seven,_Plus_or_Minus_Two) and the [Jam Study](https://hbr.org/2006/06/more-isnt-always-better).